# How can I do this better without checking getClientOriginalName() on uploaded files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['resim'] = Input::file('resim')->getClientOriginalName();

    $rules = array( 
        'resim'         => 'required|max:3000|image|mimes:jpg,gif,png',
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if($validation->fails())
    {
        return View::make('theme-admin.slider_add')
            ->nest('message_area', 'theme-admin.error', array('message' => $validation->messages()->first()));
    }

    ...
```

The issue is, `Input::file('resim')->getClientOriginalName();` throw exception when the image is not uploaded. (e.g when I directly click on submit button on HTML form)

However, `required|max:3000|image|mimes:jpg,gif,png` this rule does not work if I erase that line. Whether if I upload a valid image or not, it doesn't pass `mimes:jpg,gif,png` control.

How can I do this without relying on `Input::file('resim')->getClientOriginalName();`? I want `required` control to handle what's necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in the images I'm trying to upload. For some reason, some of my JPG files couldn't pass the mimetype check whereas others can.

They all passed with `getClientOriginalName()` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Input has file with name attribute as 'resim'
$rules = array('resim' => 'required|max:3000|image|mimes:jpg,gif,png');

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::to('...')->withErrors($validator);
}

...
```

Comment: Read my question. I know about this. The problem is, no valid image passes image|mimes:jpg,gif,png check if I use it like this, because $input['resim'] doesn't contain what getClientOriginalName() returns.

Comment: If you know about this, why don't you use it?! It works + answers your question! Try remove 'image' from your rules and see if that helps. If it doesn't, then there's some evil spirit involved!

Comment: I have just tried the code, it validates all rules: **required|max:3000|image|mimes:jpg,gif,png**

Comment: Because it does not work on my installation and it does not answer my question. I have tried the exact same thing. You'd see that if you could read the question. It does NOT pass validation without "getClientOriginalName()".

Comment: Then you definitely have a problem somewhere else in your code. I do not think it's a matter of whose installation is the 'the chosen one' in order for stuff to work. What does your form look like?

Comment: The problem lies in the image itself. For some reason, my valid JPG files can't pass mime check, whereas PNG files pass it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.